# generate px.line graph (graph in web browser window). pytohn, pycharm, kmeans, graph, plotly

Tags: python, dataframe, graph, plotly, k-means

I have a working code that makes perfectly working graph with command `plt.plot(df, cs.predict(df), 'o')`. Its the right outpu but I need to make that graph in web browser window.(my teacher wants it that way). I got another code and it works with this:

```
fig = px.line(new_dataset2, x='time', y="value", title='coffee-machine wattage')
fig.show()
```

Its a different .csv file but u get the idea, the graph looks like this:
[image]
the thing is it wont allow me to plot by px.line. Is there some way how to transform the plt.plot to plx.line?
I tried this:

```
fig = px.line(cs.predict(df), x='_time', y="_value", title='coffee-machine wattage',)
fig.show()
```

but it throws an error

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matus\PycharmProjects\fridge\cofeemashine-kmeans.py", line 28, in <module>
    fig = px.line(cs.predict(df), x='_time', y="_value", title='coffee-machine wattage',)
  File "C:\Users\matus\PycharmProjects\fridge\permut\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_chart_types.py", line 264, in line
    return make_figure(args=locals(), constructor=go.Scatter)
  File "C:\Users\matus\PycharmProjects\fridge\permut\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 1990, in make_figure
    args = build_dataframe(args, constructor)
  File "C:\Users\matus\PycharmProjects\fridge\permut\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 1405, in build_dataframe
    df_output, wide_id_vars = process_args_into_dataframe(
  File "C:\Users\matus\PycharmProjects\fridge\permut\lib\site-packages\plotly\express\_core.py", line 1207, in process_args_into_dataframe
    raise ValueError(err_msg)
ValueError: Value of 'x' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. Expected one of [0] but received: _time

Process finished with exit code 1
"
```

I will post my code, graph and part of my .csv file

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import cluster as cls
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px


# Read the CSV file into a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('coffee_machine_2022-11-22_09_22_influxdb_data.csv',header=0,usecols=['_time','_value'] )
print(df)
# Convert the _time column to a datetime type
df['_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_time'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

# Set the index of the DataFrame to the _time column
df = df.set_index('_time')

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
# df.interpolate(method='linear') # not neccesary
cs = cls.KMeans(n_clusters=4)

cs.fit(df)
print(cs.predict([[1200]]))

plt.plot(df, cs.predict(df), 'o')
plt.show()

#below doesnt work
fig = px.line(cs.predict(df), x='_time', y="_value", title='coffee-machine wattage',)
fig.show()
```

This is that working graph I need to change [image]

part of my .csv file:

```
result,table,_start,_stop,_time,_value,_field,_measurement,device
,0,2022-10-23T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-11-22T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-10-24T12:12:35Z,44.61,power,shellies,Shelly_Kitchen-C_CoffeMachine/relay/0
,0,2022-10-23T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-11-22T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-10-24T12:12:40Z,17.33,power,shellies,Shelly_Kitchen-C_CoffeMachine/relay/0
,0,2022-10-23T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-11-22T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-10-24T12:12:45Z,41.2,power,shellies,Shelly_Kitchen-C_CoffeMachine/relay/0
,0,2022-10-23T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-11-22T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-10-24T12:12:51Z,33.49,power,shellies,Shelly_Kitchen-C_CoffeMachine/relay/0
,0,2022-10-23T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-11-22T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-10-24T12:12:56Z,55.68,power,shellies,Shelly_Kitchen-C_CoffeMachine/relay/0
,0,2022-10-23T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-11-22T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-10-24T12:12:57Z,55.68,power,shellies,Shelly_Kitchen-C_CoffeMachine/relay/0
,0,2022-10-23T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-11-22T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-10-24T12:13:02Z,25.92,power,shellies,Shelly_Kitchen-C_CoffeMachine/relay/0
,0,2022-10-23T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-11-22T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-10-24T12:13:08Z,5.71,power,shellies,Shelly_Kitchen-C_CoffeMachine/relay/0
,0,2022-10-23T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-11-22T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-10-24T12:13:14Z,553.75,power,shellies,Shelly_Kitchen-C_CoffeMachine/relay/0
,0,2022-10-23T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-11-22T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-10-24T12:13:19Z,5.71,power,shellies,Shelly_Kitchen-C_CoffeMachine/relay/0
,0,2022-10-23T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-11-22T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-10-24T12:13:24Z,8.95,power,shellies,Shelly_Kitchen-C_CoffeMachine/relay/0
,0,2022-10-23T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-11-22T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-10-24T12:13:26Z,5.69,power,shellies,Shelly_Kitchen-C_CoffeMachine/relay/0
,0,2022-10-23T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-11-22T08:22:04.124457277Z,2022-10-24T12:13:30Z,5.63,power,shellies,Shelly_Kitchen-C_CoffeMachine/relay/0
```

Comment: Have you looked at what `cs.predict(df)` contains? It does not contain the data that's in `df`. Your error is telling you that there is no column named `_value`, nor `time`. You could add `cs.predict(df)` to your data frame, then have all three variables (the groups, time, and value). An easy way to see what's in your objects is to either `print` or add a breakpoint at the end of your code and run the debugger. The debugger is great for exploring your objects (even if there's nothing wrong with your code).

Answer (score 0):

As @Kat stated, the columns in the output of `cs.predict(df)` are named differently than those in `df`, and that is what the error is telling to you.

It seems that the output of `cs.predict(df)` contains only one column that is named `0`. Given that, a possible solution for you could be:

```
pred = cs.predict(df).rename(columns={0: "_pred"})
plot_df = pd.concat([pred, df["_time"]], axis="columns")

fig = px.line(plot_df, x="_time", y="_pred", title='coffee-machine wattage')
fig.show()
```